# Writing List of object into CSV File in xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android

Can any one suggest me  How to implement writing List of objects into .csv into device download storage in c# xamarin android.The data exported to csv should be having headers.each item in list should be written in row .something similar to image attached [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have followed below link http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/08/03/generate-a-csv-from-a-generic-list-of-objects-using-reflection-and-extension-methods/  that helped me to implement.

Answer (score 0):

To create a CSV string, you'd generally do this manually.  As an example:

`string headers = $"{Column1},{Column2}";`
`string row1 = $"{row1.ValueA},{row1.ValueB}";`

...etc...

Then append them together, separated by newlines. Obviously you'd be better off doing the above in some kind of loop.

As for putting it into android download storage, someone else will have to tell you how to do that, I don't know how!